# How to box part of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, boxes

About this code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight, italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\newcommand*{\arabicdec}[1]{\the\numexpr\value{#1}-1\relax}
%\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabicdec{chapter}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabicdec{section}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}


\begin{document}

\title{\color{red}{\Huge{\textbf{ALGEBRA LINEARE}}}}
\author{\color{blue}{\Huge{\textbf{???}}}}
\date{27 Febbraio 2021 $-$ xx Mese Anno}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\dominitoc

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section*{PREFAZIONE GENERALE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}PREFAZIONE GENERALE}

\mainmatter

\chapter{NOTAZIONI PRELIMINARI}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{??}

\newpage

\part{\huge\color{red}{FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE}}

\section*{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}
\Large{Inserire una Prefazione}

\chapter{One}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip

\section{One.One}
\subsection{One.One.One}
\subsubsection{One.One.One.One}

\end{document}
```

That compiles as this photo:

[image: Contents1]

I'd like to box this part:

[image: Contents1boxed]

And I'd like to have that points (... number page) start from right side of the box. Is it possible? Thank you and Best Regards

Comment: unrelated but you should really stop to put formatting instructions everywhere. It should be \part{FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE} and not `\part{\huge\color{red}{FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE}}`.

Comment: Unrelated? Why?

Comment: @John Kormylo thank you, but I need the tex code. Please. Thx

Answer (score 1):

This uses `\tikzmark` to locate the corners of the box.  The dots were delayed by adding `\hspace`, where the distances needed were also computed using `\tikzmark` (then removed).

Note the use of `\ifTOC` and `\mytikzmark`.  It is important that every `\tikzmark` name be used only once.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight, italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newif{\ifTOC}

\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{\ifTOC\tikzmark{#1}\fi}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\newcommand*{\arabicdec}[1]{\the\numexpr\value{#1}-1\relax}
%\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabicdec{chapter}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabicdec{section}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\title{\color{red}{\Huge{\textbf{ALGEBRA LINEARE}}}}
\author{\color{blue}{\Huge{\textbf{???}}}}
\date{27 Febbraio 2021 $-$ xx Mese Anno}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\dominitoc

\TOCtrue
\tableofcontents
\TOCfalse

\newpage

\section*{PREFAZIONE GENERALE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}PREFAZIONE GENERALE}

\mainmatter

\chapter{NOTAZIONI PRELIMINARI}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{??}

\newpage

\part[FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE]%
  {\huge\color{red}{FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE}}

\section*{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}
\Large{Inserire una Prefazione}

\chapter{One}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip

\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxA}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{116pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{64pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[One.One.One.One\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxB}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxA)+(-2pt,2pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxB)+(2pt,-2pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok thank you Very much?

Comment: If I'd like to have that the box is away few pt from \chapter, how must I do? Thank you

Comment: You will note that the two corners are already being offset by 2pt and `\dp\strutbox` (the distance from the baseline to the bottom of the text space).  If OTOH you want to add some space, just put a `\vskip` into the `\addtocontents` after `\chapter`.

Comment: OTOH? What is??

Comment: On The Other Hand (I use it a lot).

Comment: Thank you very much, but the position of \vskip{} is wrong. Could you edit your code using \vskip{3pt}, please? Thank very much

Comment: How odd, I solved it by putting a `\vspace` instead of `\vskip`. It's normal?

Comment: The two are almost interchangible.  The main difference is that \vspace waits until the end of the current line to execute.

Comment: Ok, thank you!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128635/discussion-between-puck-and-john-kormylo).