# Better vertical spacing between boxes and chapter in tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, conditionals, boxes, tikzmark, vspace

About this code, I'd like to personalize spacing between boxes and chapter in tableofcontents

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight, italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newif{\ifTOC}

\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[1]{\ifTOC\tikzmark{#1}\fi}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\newcommand*{\arabicdec}[1]{\the\numexpr\value{#1}-1\relax}
%\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\arabicdec{chapter}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabicdec{section}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\title{\color{red}{\Huge{\textbf{ALGEBRA LINEARE}}}}
\author{\color{blue}{\Huge{\textbf{???}}}}
\date{27 Febbraio 2021 $-$ xx Mese Anno}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\dominitoc

\TOCtrue
\tableofcontents
\TOCfalse

\newpage

\section*{PREFAZIONE GENERALE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}PREFAZIONE GENERALE}

\mainmatter

\chapter{NOTAZIONI PRELIMINARI}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{??}

\newpage

\part[FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE]%
  {\huge\color{red}{FONDAMENTI DELL'ALGEBRA LINEARE}}

\section*{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Prefazione alla Prima Parte}
%\Large{Inserire una Prefazione}

\chapter{One}
\minitoc %\minilof\minilot
\mtcskip

\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxA}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{130pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{78pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[Very long Expression\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxB}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxA)+(-2pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxB)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
  
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxC}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{116pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{64pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[One.One.One.One\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxD}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxC)+(-5pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxD)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
      
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxE}}%
\section[One.One\string\hspace{116pt}]{One.One}
\subsection[One.One.One\string\hspace{64pt}]{One.One.One}
\subsubsection[One.One.One.One\string\mytikzmark{TOCboxF}]{One.One.One.One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\tikz[overlay,remember picture]% make sure on same apge
  {\string\draw ($(pic cs:TOCboxE)+(-5pt,3pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$) rectangle 
      ($(pic cs:TOCboxF)+(3pt,0pt-\the\dp\strutbox)$);}}%
      

\end{document}
```

How could I do? Thank you very much and Best Regards.

**First Edit:** Furthermore, does a way exist to create a strutbox for all section? Thank you

**Second Edit:** Adding this photo, I hope my question is clearer, isn't it?

[image: Contents TikZ]

Comment: as noted in some of your earlier questions, size commands do not take an argument. `\Large{Inserire una Prefazione}` makes the rest of the document Large, it does not apply that size to `{Inserire una Prefazione}`

Comment: Ok, thx, hence?

Comment: If you keep posting the same code with the same errors even after multiple comments eg [this one from Ulrike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610732/how-to-box-part-of-contents#comment1527553_610732)  or [this from me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610654/incorrect-position-of-minitocs#comment1527476_610654) people are less likely to feel inclined to answer. If you make the entire document be in the scope of `\Large` then all vertical spacing will be wrong, so you should fix that first before looking at other details of your code.

Comment: I commented \Large, now could you answer, please?

Comment: Actually, I just said it: I'd like to personalize the vertical space between the chapter and the box below. I can edit again my question, even adding a photo, in order to clear you what I desire.

Comment: just copy the definintion of `\l@chapter`  from book.cls and add `\vspace{10pt}` at the end.

Comment: Is this: `\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@`, isn't it ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: your last comment isn't understandable. Could you be clearer or, you'd better, could you copy and edit (where it needs) my code? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout of the table of contents is specified by `\l@...` commands so `\l@chapter` here. There are packages that give a higher level interface but here it is simple to copy the original definition and adjust the spacing if that is the only change needed.

I just added the commented line to the definition and added to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
% copied from book
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil
      \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2%
                                 \kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
\vspace{-10pt}% or whatever
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Producing

[image]

with space after  **1 One** reduced by 10pt.

Note the initial chapter then over prints so you would have to make additional space changes elsewhere to  complete the job

Comment: Ok thank you, but now I have the section 0.0 over chapter 0. How could I solv it? What are other packages that You mentioned in you answer? Thank you very much

Comment: And how do you create those red rectangles in your photo? Thx again

Comment: @Puck I just used your code That is the standard (fairly horrible) default hyperref behaviour for links.

Comment: oh packages such as tocsty

Comment: And about KOMA-package? Could It improve my situation?

Comment: And however, neverthless I use hyperref-package I don't have those rectangles. Why?

Comment: the rectangles are added by the pdf viewer (they do not appear when you print) so you must be using a pdf viewer configured not to show them (or does not support them) which is surprising but possible.

Comment: In my question I added **First Edit:**. Could you answer also it? Please, thank you

Comment: No out of time (and as I said on the previous question don't add multiple questions and don't edit the questions to change them, only to add clarifications (like the output image)

Comment: Ok, then I create a New Question. Thank you again.

Comment: [New link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610901/tikz-newcommand-to-improve-my-toc)